# Temperature Prompt User for Console Application?

Tags: c#, temperature

(C# Visual Studio 2019) Hello, my professor wants us to do the following code shown in the picture :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONNSV.png

We are fairly new into the course and have have talked about only a few of conversion methods.

Here is my attempt, but with an error that I cannot seem to wrap my head around. If someone can help me out or provide a solution, thanks!

```
        Console.Write("Enter degrees Fahrenheit to convert to Celsius OR \nenter degrees Celsius 
        to convert to Fahrenheit.");
        Console.Write("\n\nCurrent temperature scale (C for Celsius; F for Fahrenheit): ");
        double tempscale = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Current degrees: ");
        double currentdeg = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        double degreeCelsius = 5 / 9 * (tempscale - 32);
        double degreeFahrenheit = 9 / 5 * (degreeCelsius + 32);
    
        if (tempscale == degreeFahrenheit)
            Console.Write(degreeFahrenheit + "degrees Fahrenheit is" + degreeCelsius + "degrees Celsius");
        if (tempscale == degreeCelsius)
            Console.Write(degreeCelsius + "degrees Celsius is" + degreeFahrenheit + "degrees Fahrenheit");
        Console.Write("\n\nPress any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: 1st thing is that you are not allowing to enter C or F, which is the first condition. You are reading user input and then trying to convert C/F to double. Sounds not correct :)

Comment: How do I correct the double to a letter?

Answer (score 0):

if you write `5 / 9` in your code, you are doing integer division which is a little different from what you expect:

```
int x = 5;  
int y = 9;

int result = x / y; // result is 0
```

if you divide 2 integers the result is an integer and for integer division that results in a fraction the result is rounded towards zero (everything after the decimal sign is discarded)

try writing floating point literals either as `5f` for a float or `5d` for a double...

`5d / 9d` should do what you expected

Answer (score 0):

Your first goal is to get C/F from user. Let's make simple method for it. It will return C or F, based on user input.
Or you could use enum.

```
enum TemperatureScales { Celsius, Fahrenheit }
```

Here is sample of method to get temperature scale.

```
private static char GetTemperatureScale()
{
    // Will wait for correct input from user
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter C or F");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (input == "C" || input == "F")  // you could improve and check for 'c' and 'f'
        {
            return input[0]; // you could use enum here if you are familiar with it
        }
    }
}
```

Use it in your code to ensure valid input.